# Change WAV File In C

Tags: c, file, wav

I'm trying to change WAV File factor with C.
i need to multiple all bytes with the factor i'm getting from the user.
i wrote a function that read 2 bytes and return a short int type.
but i can get the OUTPUT file be as the  OUT file from the Example program i have.
Please help ** Attaching Code

```
void modify_data(unsigned char*buffer, char *name, long filelen, float factor){
short  temp=0;
char byte[2]={0};
FILE *fp=NULL;
int i,big=0;
unsigned int check=0;
char *str=strtok(name,".");

sprintf(name,"%s‫‪_modified‬‬.wav",name);
fp=fopen(name,"wb");
fwrite(buffer,1,44,fp);
for (i=44;i<filelen;i+=2){
    check=0;
    temp= (short)read_short(i,buffer);

    printf("%hu\n",temp);
    /*check=(int)(temp | check);
    check=check*factor;
    printf("%d\n",check);

    //getchar();
*/
    if ((roundf(temp*factor))>= MAX16BIT){
     temp=MAX16BIT;
    printf("True\n");
    } 
    else {  
        if  ((roundf(temp*factor)) <= -1*MAX16BIT) temp=-1*MAX16BIT;
        else temp=(short)round((double)(temp*factor));
    }
    byte[0] = (temp & 0xFF);
        byte[1] = ((temp & 0xFF00)>>8);
    fwrite(byte,1,2,fp);
    temp=0;
    }
fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Note that "neutral" value for WAV files is not 0 but "middle" (32768 in 16 bit mode). In other words you have to multiply the values above and below 32767/8 to upper and lower values.

Comment: " i can get the new file be as the file i need it to be" [sic] You are not telling us what the problem is. For all we know, you want the new file to contain tomorrow's lottery numbers. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and use [edit] to clarify your post.

Comment: Ok.. U r right.. i have an example program that take the factor and update the file with the factor.. i can get my output file be as the Example output file..@ i486 .. what do u mean? should i use round function on factor?